# Boolean logic for input validation

Tags: java, arraylist, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

i have a method that continues to loop until the user inputs a number within a set range. Basically it reads the size on an arraylist, and validates that the users input is greater than -1, and and less than the arraylist size. Howver, i cant seem to get the boolean logic right and it still accepts bad numbers or only one side of the range works. Here is the code

```
public void Verify()
{
    
    do {
        System.out.printf("Enter the number\n");
        while (!input.hasNextInt()) 
        {
            System.out.printf("Enter the number\n");
                            input.next();
        }
        choice = input.nextInt();
    } while (choice < 0 && choice >  mov.getArrayListSize());//<--- this part
    
}
```

Comment: Just negate the whole thing and it should be ok. `while ( !(choice >= 0 && choice <  mov.getArrayListSize()))`

Comment: @Amongalen just tried it and didnt work. another other suggestions

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper still no dice... the logic makes sense but now it accepts no number at all ?

Comment: Matthew have you tried Amongalens version or the version you edited into the question? Because your version is a wrong "translation" of Amongalens version.

Comment: @Tom i tried his first, before editing the post, and then i tried the version written in the edit. neither worked for me unfortunately

Comment: Then it is about time to create a [mre].

Comment: @MatthewJoel I have no idea what you did with my suggestion (hence why I deleted it after your comment stating that it didn't work), but I just tested it and it does what I'd expect it to do. See [this proof of concept](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/5oY).

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper i plugged in right in and tested it, i think my programs just wonky all around and yeah it works perfect in j doodle. thanks for the help tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the problem

```
while (choice < 0 && choice >  mov.getArrayListSize());
```

What this says is: keep looping until the value of choice is both less than zero and simultaneously greater than the size of the array. Let's look at some number lines:

```
xxxxxxxxxx
----------+---------+------------>   ... this shows a solution for choice < 0
          0         len

                     xxxxxxxxxxxx
----------+---------+------------>   ... this shows a solution for choice > len
          0         len


----------+---------+------------>   ... this shows a solution for the logical AND
          0         len
```

There is no solution for choice that can possibly be both less than zero and more than the array length. What you almost certainly mean to use is logical OR, not AND:

```
while (choice < 0 || choice >  mov.getArrayListSize());
```

The solution on the number line for this is

```
xxxxxxxxxx           xxxxxxxxxxxx
----------+---------+------------>   ... this shows a solution for choice > len
          0         len
```

The loop would continue until the value fell inside the 0-len range, which seems like what you need here.